# specifying the index of new elements being added to an array via a loop javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a small question web app using javascript/html. Currently the app is able to keep a track of which question is currently visible on the page. There are 2 buttons on the page, a next and a previous button. When the user selects an radio button, the value of that radio button is pushed onto an array that keeps a track of the users answers. What I would like to do is, add the value of the radio button the user has chosen to a specific index in the new "savedAns" array. Because the variable "count" keeps a track of the currently visible questions, is there a way to push the value of each radio button to its corresponding index "count" each time?

```js
let savedAns = [];

const radios = document.getElementsByName('answer');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
const quizes = document.querySelectorAll('.quiz');
const total = quizes.length;
//keep a track of which question is visible 
let count = 0;

//function to hide all the quizes
const hide = function() {
  quizes.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.display = 'none'
  })
}

//show and hide divs when user presses next
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count < total - 1) {
    count++;
    prevCount++;
    radios.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.checked) {
        savedAns.push(element.value)
      }
    })
  } else {
    alert('no more questions left')
    return
  }
  hide();
  quizes[count].style.display = 'block'
})
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
  } else {
    alert('no more previous questions')
    return
  }
  hide();
  quizes[count].style.display = 'block'
})
```

```html
<div class="quiz">
  <p>Question 1</p>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
</div>

<div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
  <p>Question 2</p>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
</div>

<div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
  <p>Question 3</p>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Any information towards the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you go to a previous question, will it be possible to update an answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should've explained it a bit clearer in the post my apologies. So when the user goes back to a previous question and selects a new answer, the array should ideally update with the new answer for the previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reassing Elements

*array[i] = x*

Instead of **using push** store the element at the position of *count* **reassign the elements**.

#### Own Class Names

In this solution there is also a change to the structure of class names. To always get only the options of the current question the input of the questions have a classname corresponding to its count. First question `class = "quiz1"`, the second `class = "quiz2"` and so on.

Inside the event listener function we can than get the inputs of the current question with

```
document.getElementsByClassName(`quiz${count+1}`)
```

You can check witch of these radio buttons is checked in a loop and assign the value of the checked one to the array at position count.

```
 if (x.checked) {
        savedAns[count] = x.value;
```

```js
let savedAns = [];


const radios = document.getElementsByName('answer');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
const quizes = document.querySelectorAll('.quiz');

// Add to all quizes inputs the specific class names
// Here is the updated part
quizes.forEach((x, ind) => [...x.children].forEach((y) => {
if(y.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input'){
y.classList.add(`quiz${ind+1}`);
}
}))

const total = quizes.length - 1;
//keep a track of which question is visible 
let count = 0;



//function to hide all the quizes
const hide = function() {
  quizes.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.display = 'none'
  })
}

//show and hide divs when user presses next
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count < total) {
    const currentAnswers = [...document.getElementsByClassName(`quiz${count+1}`)];
    currentAnswers.forEach((x, i) => {
      if (x.checked) {
        savedAns[count] = x.value;
        console.log(savedAns);
      }
    })
    count++;

  } else {
    alert('no more questions left')
    return
  }
  hide();
  quizes[count].style.display = 'block'
})
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count > 0) {
    const currentAnswers = [...document.getElementsByClassName(`quiz${count+1}`)];
    currentAnswers.forEach((x, i) => {
      if (x.checked) {
        savedAns[count] = x.value;
        console.log(savedAns);
      }
    })
    count--;
  } else {
    alert('no more previous questions')
    return
  }
  hide();
  quizes[count].style.display = 'block'

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quiz">
  <p>Question 1</p>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
</div>

<div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
  <p>Question 2</p>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
</div>

<div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
  <p>Question 3</p>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I was wondering if I could ask a small question related to your solution, with input having their own unique class name I was wondering if this could be changed dynamically with this solution-i.e. if I didn't know how many questions there would be for the app?

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation I'll give it a go :)